# geb passing test case as a parameter from maven commandline

Tags: maven, testing, groovy, command-line, geb

How do I pass the test case to geb via maven commandline:

I have a test case class named GebishOrgSpec2.groovy 
I want to pass this test case maven and let geb run it over the command line.
I am having successful build but no run of the test case
How do I solve this problem?

This is my pom.xml

```
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>${inc.TestCase}</include>
          </includes>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <geb.build.reportsDir>target/test-reports/geb</geb.build.reportsDir>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

I have tried the following codes and they are all not running the testcase

```
mvn -Dinc.TestCase=GebishOrgSpec2.groovy test
mvn -Dinclude=GebishOrgSpec2.groovy test
mvn install -Dinc.TestCase=GebishOrgSpec2.groovy 
mvn install -Dinclude=GebishOrgSpec2.groovy
```

I have tried these links
[How to run Geb TestCases from windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55324604/how-to-run-geb-testcases-from-windows-command-line)

[Grails geb getting parameters from commandline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35840678/grails-geb-getting-parameters-from-commandline)

[Geb exception when running tests in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36227008/geb-exception-when-running-tests-in-maven)

they are all not working

> System.getProperty("inc.TestCase") is returning null as well
>   I want to add that if I add the test case directly into the pom it does run successfully
>   can you please help

Comment: I would appreciate feedback to my answer. I took time to test and write it for you and add links to documentation websites.

Comment: @kriegaex I would like to first of apologize for the delay of my feedback. I was trying to pass additional user defined variables which where not working and this took my attention away.  Please I plead with you to accept my apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use in-/excludes in your POM for something you want to do from the command line. It is much easier, both for

- [Surefire (unit tests)](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html) via `mvn -Dtest=TestCircle test` and
- [Failsafe (integration tests)](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/single-test.html) via `mvn -Dit.test=ITCircle verify`

This works beautifully for Spock/Geb tests.